# recommended subdir structure for files in ng2 app subdir

Tags: angular

I pulled down an ng2 quickstart project and all of the files were in the "app" subdir.  I'm using this project as a base for adding some additional components of my own. I added my new files at the same single level in the app subdir but I feel that a subdirectory structure would make the component files easier to manage. What kind of subfolder structure do you normally use for this?

Comment: This is ultimately subjective, but with Angular 2's heavy focus on components a directory per component/feature may prove the most natural 'fit' for your project as it grows. The idea being that each directory provides a cleanly delineated building block/feature of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Angular provides a style guide that covers this and most of other construction of Angular apps. Check it out here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html